# Python - split data in list when we detect symbol ('|')

Tags: python

I wouldlike to split my list when I detect this '|'
Something like this :

```
list A = ['abc', 'bcd', 'cde', '|', 'iojfsdifdosj', 'iojsdfiosjf', '|', 'jhuh']

out : 
['abc,bcd,cde', 'iojfsdifdosj,iojsdfiosjf']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution would be to concatenate `list_A` into a single string and then split it by pipes.

```py
str_list_A = ",".join(list_A)
out = str_list_A.split(",|,")
```

Comment: thx you @notacorn ! if I want to seperate with ',' ? because if i use ",".join(list_A) i have in output : [',abc,....]

Comment: oh my bad lemme handle that detail